How can I layer two backgrounds over each other in a way that they do not clash in Tailwind?
I'm trying to have a container act as an accent of sorts for another container. As in I have a text box that is styled and underneath it I'm trying to have a similarly sized container of a different background color that can be shifted to the bottom-right to act as a sort of accent for the container. The closest I've been able to get is: (Disregard the colors)
          <div className="space-y-6">
            <p className="relative font-dmSans text-md leading-tight text-white-classic bg-yellow-600 mt-2 z-20 p-4 ">
              <span className="absolute bottom-3 right-3 h-full w-full bg-black -z-10 "></span>
              Body of my text is here.
            </p>

It kind of does what I would like for it to but the problem is it positions the text within the box(understandably). My ultimate goal is to be able to position the yellow box and have it behind the black. Other attempts caused a clash where the other container was present over this container(though i'll admit im pretty new and poor with before: and after: Another reason I tried to do it like this is because this way didn't interfere with the structure of my styling.
Is there another way I can do this to where I can shift the yellow box directly and still have it behind the black one that holds my text?
I'm trying to create a staggered container/accent effect using z-index and before I tried to leverage Tailwind before: and after: classes but the background would shine through the container and z-index would not affect it.

Would box-shadow achieve the effect instead of adding an otherwise spurious element to the DOM?

Thanks for your reply. I'm specifically going for a staggered/overlapping tile effect with this box. I saw a youtube video showing them leveraging before:z-10 etc and it worked for them and that's initially what I was going for but when I introduced a different bg-color it just refused to behave the way I wanted it to :/ I wanted to also avoid extra elements if I could.

If I understand you correctly, what you want should be the effect below:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="relative m-4 space-y-6">
  <div class="absolute left-2 top-2 h-full w-full bg-yellow-400"></div>
  <p class="font-dmSans text-md relative bg-black p-4 leading-tight text-white">
    Body of my text is here.
  </p>
</div>



Using absolute can position the yellow element relative to the first relative ancestor to achieve the offset effect. However, note that your <p> element also needs to be set to relative; otherwise, it will appear behind all absolute sibling elements.
